# Replacing a string with symbols using font-lock?

Tags: elisp

I'm trying to make a font lock hook to replace strings of text for a mathmatical notation plugin.

So I'm thinking " / " (note the spaces) will turn into " ÷ ", but "/" won't. (It's a package mainly for R statistical language.)

I'm playing with the examples from the manual and I can't even get that to work lol. I was trying to get the word `FIXIT` to change font color.

```
(add-hook 'emacs-lisp-mode-hook
        (lambda ()
        (font-lock-add-keywords nil
            '(("\\<\\(FIXIT\\):" 1
            font-lock-warning-face t)))))
```

I don't even fully understand the syntax since I'm just getting used to lisp. Does it use a RegEx to identify strings? and if so, what RegEx engine.

I was hoping it would change the font color, but it didnt... but again, that was just me playing with it trying to understand it, not the end goal. The end result would be the first thing I mentioned to change math symbols.

Answer (score 0):

As far as your example is concerned: Perhaps you're missing the ":" after FIXIT? Try pasting

```
;; FIXIT: needs work
```

into an elisp buffer with your hook enabled, it should work.

As far as regular expressions are concerned, their syntax is detailed in the user manual under [Regexps](https://www.gnu.org/software/emacs/manual/html_node/emacs/Regexps.html) and in the Elisp manual under [Syntax of Regexps](https://www.gnu.org/software/emacs/manual/html_node/elisp/Syntax-of-Regexps.html).

I'm not too sure whether font-lock can actually help in your case. One way to change displayed text would be to use [Text Properties](https://www.gnu.org/software/emacs/manual/html_node/elisp/Text-Properties.html), specifically the [Display Property](https://www.gnu.org/software/emacs/manual/html_node/elisp/Display-Property.html). The following code changes all slashes to "÷" if surrounded by spaces.

```
(while (re-search-forward " \\(/\\) " nil t)
  (put-text-property (match-beginning 1)
                     (match-end 1)
                     'display "÷"))
```

However, unlike font-lock, which applies fonts as text changes, this would be "permanent" until the text is deleted or the property changed. <s>If fonts could do the same (e.g. via a display property of the font itself), you might find yourself lucky, otherwise you'll have to find a workaround that is not reimplementing font-lock.</s>

**Edit:** It turns out, that you can use `jit-lock-register` to run your own fontification functions. Based on observations made by inspecting the source of `glasses-mode` I've written a minor mode that does what you want as a proof of concept. It uses [overlays](http://www.gnu.org/software/emacs/manual/html_node/elisp/Overlays.html) rather than text properties, because those are easier to remove.

```
(defun make-divisions-fancy (beg end)
  (save-excursion
    (save-match-data
      (goto-char beg)
      (while (re-search-forward " \\(/\\) " end t)
        (let ((overlay (make-overlay (match-beginning 1)
                                     (match-end 1)
                                     nil t)))
          (overlay-put overlay 'category 'fancy-divide)
          (overlay-put overlay 'evaporate t)
          (overlay-put overlay 'display "÷"))))))

(defun make-divisions-boring (beg end)
  (dolist (o (overlays-in beg end))
    (when (eq (overlay-get o 'category) 'fancy-divide)
      (delete-overlay o))))

(defun remake-fancy-divisions (beg end)
  (make-divisions-boring beg end)
  (make-divisions-fancy beg end))

(define-minor-mode fancy-div-mode
  "Minor mode to make divisions like \" / \" fancier."
  :init-value nil 
  (save-excursion
    (save-restriction
      (widen)
      (make-divisions-boring (point-min) (point-max))
      (if fancy-div-mode
          (jit-lock-register 'remake-fancy-divisions)
        (jit-lock-unregister 'remake-fancy-divisions)))))
```